# How to change class names of variables stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function hideTitle(){
  var k = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title');
  for (var i = 0;i < k.length ; i++) {
    k[i].className = "menu-title-after-click" ;
    /*document.getElementById("menu-title").className="menu-title-after-click";*/
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.menu-title{
  /*padding-left: 2px;*/
  padding-left: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  visibility: visible;
  /*display: none;*/
}

.menu-title-after-click{
  /*display: none;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="hideTitle();">hide/show title</button>
```

In the above i'm tried to hide the menu-title when click on the button associated with it.i trying to do that by changing the class name.but it's not working functionally,it's just hide the menu-titles on odd positions and on continuous clicks it hides all. i don't know why,i want to fix this,how can i fix this?

> my **primary requirement** is to change the class names of elements
>   stored in an array.then only to hide the menu-title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always using classList is more easy to understand and is working. Check this

Also you can easily handle classes with remove and add.

**Edited**: Now its not giving console.log errors and its toggling all the classes

```js
function hideTitle(){
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title');
    for (var i = 0;i < k.length ; i++) {
        if (k[i].classList.contains("menu-title-after-click")) {
            k[i].classList.remove("menu-title-after-click");
        } else {
            k[i].classList.add("menu-title-after-click");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  }
.menu-title{
    /*padding-left: 2px;*/
    padding-left: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
    visibility: visible;
    /*display: none;*/
}

.menu-title-after-click{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title1</span>
  </li>
   <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title2</span>
  </li>
   <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">title3</span>
  </li>
<ul>
  <button type="button" onclick="hideTitle()">hide/show title</button>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to change <= to < in the for loop now is fully funcitonal

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hideTitle() {
        var k = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title');
        for (var i = 0;i < k.length  ; i++) {           
           addClass(k[i],'menu-title-after-click');
        }
}

function addClass(el, cls) {
  if (hasClass(el,cls)) {
            var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
            el.className=el.className.replace(reg,' ');
  } 
  else 
  {
     if (el.classList)
       el.classList.add(cls)
     }
}

function hasClass(el,cls) {
    return el.className.match(new    RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  }
.menu-title{
    /*padding-left: 2px;*/
    padding-left: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
    visibility: visible;
    /*display: none;*/
}

.menu-title-after-click{
    /*display: none;*/
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span  class="menu-title">title1</span>
  </li>
   <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span  class="menu-title">title2</span>
  </li>
   <li>
    <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
    <span  class="menu-title">title3</span>
  </li>
<ul>
  <button type="button" onclick="hideTitle();">hide/show title</button>
```

Comment: using jQuery in the project, you dont need to create addClass or hasClass or removeClass and ...